# I cannot call https API from cordova app, how can i do this?

Tags: android, cordova, https, quasar-framework, quasar

I'm developing an app using Quasar Framework and cordova.

I'm trying to call an https API from my cordova app and it didn't work. This is a common issue and i found a lot of answers here but nothing worked for me.

Major topics says that we hava to to this in config.xml, and i did it, but didn't work:

```
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
    <platform name="android">
         <access origin="*" />
        <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
        <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
        <allow-navigation href="*" />
        <allow-navigation href="about:*" />
    </platform>
```

The funny thing is: if i try to emulate the app on android studio, or even in my android device, it works perfectly! But if i try to build and install the app on android, it doesn't work.

This is my cordova requirements:

```
Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: installed android-29,android-28,android-27,android-26,android-25,android-24,android-23,android-22,android-21
Gradle: installed C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-5.1.1\bin\gradle
```

Please guys could you help me? I don't know what to do anymore.

Comment: which plugin you are using for API calls?

Comment: "It didn't work" is very vague. Maybe come up with an error

Comment: @Swayangjit Im using Axios.

Comment: @Eric Sorry, the response error is: "Error: Request aborted", im using Axios btw.

Comment: @FryKlaus need more info, how do you make the call? Paste some code...

Comment: make a small version of your project and publish on github or send photos, in order to have a better idea of what it can be, it can be many things but without seeing the code you can't.